# cURL command to POST with data embedded in request

Tags: php, linux, shell, api, curl

I am writing a **simple** shell script using which I will create a request in JIRA  when conditions are met using curl. Following is the JIRA way of executing it, which needs me to send send the request as a command and parameters using a data file:

**Request:**

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/
```

**Data:**

```
{
"fields": {
   "project":
   { 
      "key": "TEST"
   },
   "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
   "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
   "issuetype": {
      "name": "Bug"
   }}}
```

So I don't want to use a separate data file as shown above.  Rather I would like to using a single curl Request which has the data embedded in the request. Something like:

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --"**PASS ALL MY DATA HERE**" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/
```

I know it will make things cluttered, but thats the way i want it. Can you please suggest if the above is feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do it with a [here document](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection?s[]=here&s[]=document#here_documents)?

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST -d - -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/ <<EOF
{
"fields": {
  "project":
  { 
    "key": "TEST"
  },
  "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
  "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
  "issuetype": {
  "name": "Bug"
  }}}
EOF
```